# Choose all elements except on with Selector of Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to select all from the html except `<blockquote>` element. How to do this in the simpliest way using Jsoup?
I know there is a `:not` syntax, but how to use it in this example?

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        String html = "<body> <blockquote> ...remove.this... </blockquote> ...get.this... </body>";
        Document d = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element element = d.select(:not("blockquote").first(); // doesn't work
        System.out.println(element.text()); // here I want get only: `...get.this...'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntactical error in this line (your compiler should have complained about it):

```
d.select(:not("blockquote"); // doesn't work
```

This would be the valid syntax:

```
d.select(":not(blockquote)");
```

Because `select` is a [Java method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) which takes a `String` argument. So you must give it a `String`, e.g.:

```
d.select("something");
```

And this `"something"` has to be a selector. In your case: `":not(blockquote)"`.

**Another approach** would be to select all `<blockquote>` elements and [remove](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove--) them:

```
d.select("blockquote").remove()
// after that, work with d
```

Comment: I tried `":not(blockquote)"` and this brings nothing. I get: `<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <blockquote>
    ...remove.this... 
  </blockquote> ...get.this... 
 </body>
</html>` I just want to remove that blockquote block...

Comment: Then you may try to reverse your thinking. Select all `<blockquote>` elements and remove them (added it to my answer).